# Confusion about adapter pattern and inheritance (PHP)

Tags: php, inheritance, design-patterns, containers, adapter

I'm having some confusion with the adapter pattern and am wondering if it is the right tool for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Basically, I'm trying to get a class written by another developer to conform to an interface that I've written while also retaining the other methods from that class.

So I've written the following interface for a container object:

```
interface MyContainerInterface
{
    public function has($key);
    public function get($key);
    public function add($key, $value);
    public function remove($key);
}
```

I've also written an adapter that implements that interface:

```
class OtherContainerAdapter implements MyContainerInterface
{
    protected $container;
    public function __construct(ContainerInteface $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function has($key) {
        $this->container->isRegistered($key);
    }

    ...
 }
```

And am using it in my class as follows:

```
class MyClass implements \ArrayAccess
{
    protected $container;
    public function __construct(MyContainerInterface $container) {
        $this->setContainer($container);
    }

    public function offsetExists($key) {
        $this->container->has($key);
    }

    ...
}
```

Then my application uses the class as so:

```
$myClass = new MyClass(new OtherContainerAdapter(new OtherContainer));
```

The issue I'm having is that in order to use the methods from the adapter I have to write the following:

```
$myClass->getContainer()->getContainer()->has('some_key');
```

When ideally it would just be:

```
$myClass->getContainer()->has('some_key');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$myClass->getContainer()
```

should return an instance of `MyContainerInterface` and that has a `has()` function. It shouldn't have a `getContainer()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the Adapter Pattern for this.  It looks to me like you're after a polymorphic solution, which can be accomplished by simply using an abstract class.  No adapter needed.

The interface

```
interface MyContainerInterface
{
    public function has($key);
    public function get($key);
    public function add($key, $value);
    public function remove($key);
}
```

Then the abstract base class:

```
class MyContainerBaseClass implements MyContainerInterface, \ArrayAccess
{
    public function offsetExists($key) {
        $this->has($key);
    }
    ...
 }
```

Then, the sub-class from the other developer:

```
class ClassByOtherDeveloper extends MyContainerBaseClass 
{
    public function has($key) {
        $this->isRegistered($key);
    }    

    //you also need to implement get(), add(), and remove() since they are still abstract.
    ...
}
```

You can use it in your application like this:

```
$object = new ClassByOtherDeveloper();
$x = $object->has('some_key');
```

I'm assuming the `isRegistered` method lives in the implementation from the other developer.

To make it truly polymorphic you wouldn't hard-code the class name, but you'd use a variable that could come from a config file, database, or a Factory.

For example:

```
$className = "ClassByOtherDeveloper"; //this could be read from a database or some other dynamic source
$object = new $className();
$x = $object->has('some_key');
```